# What does the asterisk mean in ((CanonEOS*)ptp)->SwitchLiveView(true)

Tags: c++

I am brand new to C++ and am wondering what that asterisk means. When I search "what is the asterisk in C++" in google, it gives me info about pointers like `int *x`, which is interesting and I think I get. But what does the asterisk in this mean?

```
((CanonEOS*)ptp)->SwitchLiveView(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk after a name of a type produces a name of a pointer type based on the type in front of the asterisk.

In your case, `CanonEOS*` is the name of a pointer to `CanonEOS` type.

Overall, the expression that you posted

- Takes `ptp` pointer, and re-interprets it as a pointer to `CanonEOS`
- Calls a method `SwitchLiveView` on the `CanonEOS` instance pointed to by `ptp`, passing it `true` as the parameter.